# cors : sending request from angular to springboot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

angular code

```
onSaveUser(user:any){
     return this.http.post('http://localhost:9000/saveUser',user);
   }
```

java code @controller layer :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/")
public class UserController
{
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser")
    void saveUser(String name, String password)
    {
        userService.saveUser(name, password);
    }
}
```

error facing

[image]

trying to access controller from angular code, also set the cross origin required , but facing above error in chrome console with 403 code

Comment: Have you tried `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` without the ending slash ?

Comment: just to know more, this is the good way we integrate  angular and springboot together ?

Comment: Not really a good way. You should at least think about how you will deploy your application in production.

Comment: could you please provide some straight forward way to implement it for all

Comment: Ok so i provide you an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to remove the ending slash like that :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to CORS issue. You can provide access to all the domains from which the request will be processed by adding:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```

or for specific domains:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

or to allow more than one domains:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:4201"})
```